# How do I make Android's APK packager ignore tags files?

Tags: android, eclipse, tags

I build my [tags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) file from the src directory of my android project. I like this directory because there's no actual source code there, just top-level packages, and it's a parent directory for all of my source.

If I develop an Android Library project and use it in my Android project, then I get errors about duplicated files being added to the APK:

```
[2011-04-16 12:36:05 - myproject] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: tags
Origin 1: ~/code/android/myproject/src/tags
Origin 2: ~/code/android/LibListenScreen/src/tags
```

How can I prevent this error? My current workaround is to delete the library's tags, but that's no good.

Marking the files as Derived (in file's Properties) doesn't work. Neither does using a resource filter (in project properties). These are both Eclipse settings, but I can't find any related Android settings within Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I prevent this error?

Don't put files that are not source code in `src/`.

You are welcome to create a `pydave/` directory in your project and put the tags file there.

Comment: I edited the question to add another advantage of src: It's above source files in the file hierarchy -- this makes recursive tag building really easy. I guess my choices are to figure out nonrecursive tags, move to the project root, or move to above the project root.  I'm mostly surprised why aapt grabs these files for the apk, but I guess that's a different question.